# JQuery just created empty div doesn't have document fragment as parent

Tags: jquery, documentfragment

When creating new html node in jQuery using

```
$('<some-node>some html code</some-node>');
```

it won't become part of DOM, until you attach it. However, it does not mean, the node has no parent.

If the node was created unempty, e.g.:

```
var myNewNode = $('<div>Hello</div>');
```

You can check the parent:

```
myNewNode[0].parentNode; // Who is the parent?
```

and see you get

```
DocumentFragment
```

as result. `DocumentFragment` is some object similar to `document`, however, not part of the DOM tree.

The strange thing comes now. When you create an empty node, like

```
var myNewEmptyNode = $('<div></div>');
```

and try to check its contents

```
myNewEmptyNode[0].parentNode; // Who is now the parent?
```

surprisingly you get

```
null
```

I cannot understand this behaviour and found nothing about it in jQuery documentation. I found it when trying to debug why javascriptMVC mxui modal was failing on an empty div.

I have tested this behaviour in both Chromium and Opera, so it does not seem to be a browser related issue.

Does someone have an explanation for this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `parentNode` in that code ?!

Comment: It is the code in `Mxui.Layout.Positionable` in javascriptMVC. It's purpose is to move element from one place to another one: 

`this.element[0].parentNode.removeChild(this.element[0]);

document.body.appendChild(this.element[0]);`

Comment: @Samuel Hapak: The `appendChild` should be enough. An element can only exist at one place anyway, so it will be removed at the former place automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's due to the fact that jQuery uses `document.createElement` for "quick" HTML strings, but `jQuery.buildFragment` for all other (more "complex") HTML strings. `<div></div>` is considered quick, whereas `<div>a</div>` is not.

I set up a fiddle so you can check: http://jsfiddle.net/PzBSY/2/.

"Quick" is [defined](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L121) with the regular expression:

```
var rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/;
```

which passes the empty div string, but not the non-empty div string. Note the [`if`/`else` block](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L125) after the check which makes for the two branches.

So it's basically because jQuery explicitly builds a document fragment with the non-empty div, whereas it does not with the empty div (it just uses `document.createElement("div")` instead).

Comment: Would you please explain why they did this? I've researched and found no clue.

Comment: @hbrls Judging by [this very old post from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/), it's for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here `target` may be any valid jQuery selectors.

only `$('<div></div>')` does not create any node to your DOM. It just create it virtually but not placed it to Document. To inset it into your DOM you need to use method like `append(), appendTo(), insert()` etc.

```
$('target').append($('<div class="latest"></div>'));
$('div.latest').parent();
```

Here I inset a `div` with class `latest` and after appending it retrieve its parent node using `parent()` method.

Comment: Though it's true, you didn't answer his question at all.

Comment: @gdoron I know. but did OP throw a question to answer like an answer?

Comment: Perhaps it was not well formulated, I will try to make it more clear.